# jQuery-Form-Validator plugin: how to validate one single checkbox

Tags: jquery, validation

My form ends with a "I have read and accepted..." type of checkbox. With [jQuery-Form-Validator](http://formvalidator.net/#default-validators_checkboxgroup) plugin I can make sure the checkbox is checked using `data-validation='checkbox_group' data-validation-qty='min1'`: if unchecked the error message will say `"Please choose at least 1 item(s)"`.

Technically that's what I want, but it makes little sense semantically. It should say `"Please check this item"` or similar.

I couldn't find in the documentation how to achieve this though. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **data-validation-error-msg** parameter:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="newsletters[]" data-validation-error-msg="You have to accept the conditions" data-validation="checkbox_group" data-validation-qty="1-4" >
```